# Is it better to reduce the space complexity or the time complexity for a given program?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

> Grid Illumination: Given an NxN grid with an array of lamp coordinates. Each lamp provides illumination to every square on their x axis, every square on their y axis, and every square that lies in their diagonal (think of a Queen in chess). Given an array of query coordinates, determine whether that point is illuminated or not. The catch is when checking a query all lamps adjacent to, or on, that query get turned off. The ranges for the variables/arrays were about: 10^3 < N < 10^9, 10^3 < lamps < 10^9, 10^3 < queries < 10^9

It seems like I can get one but not both. I tried to get this down to logarithmic time but I can't seem to find a solution. I can reduce the space complexity but it's not that fast, exponential in fact. Where should I focus on instead, speed or space? Also, if you have any input as to how you would solve this problem please do comment.

Comment: Whether space complexity or time complexity is more important depends on which you have more of, and which is more important to your program.

Comment: When the adjacent lamps are turned off, do they remain off for subsequent queries?

Answer (score 1):

Is it better for a car to go fast or go a long way on a little fuel? It depends on circumstances.

Here's a proposal.

First, note you can number all the diagonals that the inputs like on by using the first point as the "origin" for both nw-se and ne-sw. The diagonals through this point are both numbered zero. The nw-se diagonals increase per-pixel in e.g the northeast direction, and decreasing (negative) to the southwest. Similarly ne-sw are numbered increasing in the e.g. the northwest direction and decreasing (negative) to the southeast.

Given the origin, it's easy to write constant time functions that go from (x,y) coordinates to the respective diagonal numbers.

Now each set of lamp coordinates is naturally associated with 4 numbers: `(x, y, nw-se diag #, sw-ne dag #)`. You don't need to store these explicitly. Rather you want 4 maps `xMap`, `yMap`, `nwSeMap`, and `swNeMap` such that, for example, xMap[x] produces the list of all lamp coordinates with x-coordinate `x`, nwSeMap[nwSeDiagonalNumber(x, y)] produces the list of all lamps on that diagonal and similarly for the other maps.

Given a query point, look up it's corresponding 4 lists.  From these it's easy to deal with adjacent squares. If any list is longer than 3, removing adjacent squares can't make it empty, so the query point is lit.  If it's only 3 or fewer, it's a constant time operation to see if they're adjacent.

This solution requires the input points to be represented in 4 lists. Since they need to be represented in one list, you can argue that this algorithm requires only a constant factor of space with respect to the input. (I.e. the same sort of cost as mergesort.)

Run time is expected constant per query point for 4 hash table lookups.

Without much trouble, this algorithm can be split so it can be map-reduced if the number of lampposts is huge.

But it may be sufficient and easiest to run it on one big machine.  With a billion lamposts and careful data structure choices, it wouldn't be hard to implement with 24 bytes per lampost in an unboxed structures language like C.  So a ~32Gb RAM machine ought to work just fine. Building the maps with multiple threads requires some synchronization, but that's done only once. The queries can be read-only: no synchronization required. A nice 10 core machine ought to do a billion queries in well less than a minute.

Answer (score 0):

There is very easy Answer which works

1. Create Grid of NxN
2. Now for each Lamp increment the count of all the cells which suppose to be illuminated by the Lamp.
3. For each query check if cell on that query has value > 0;
4. For each adjacent cell find out all illuminated cells and reduce the count by 1

This worked fine but failed for size limit when trying for 10000 X 10000 grid